# Sort an array by element frequency of appearance

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm looking for an efficient solution to sort an array depending of how many times an element appears

For example :

```
let values = ["10", "4", "4", "4", "7", "7"]
```

I think the best output would be something like `[{number, frequency}, ...]`, which, in the example would look like this :

```
[{4, 3}, {7, 2}, {10, 1}]
```

I've seen a lot of ways to do it, but every solution just sort the array depending of the frequency, without any access on how many times the element appears.

At the moment I only have this code that I got from another StackOverflow topic (can't remember which one sorry)

```
var map = values.reduce(function(p, c) {
   p[c] = (p[c] || 0) + 1;
     return p;
 }, {});

var newTypesArray = Object.keys(map).sort(function(a, b) {
     return map[a] < map[b];
 });

console.log(newTypesArray);
```

It's doing a great job at sorting depending on the frequency, but I can't access how many times an element is repeated. And I have no idea how to do it...
Any thoughts?

Comment: What is the difference between appearance and frequency?

Comment: What do you mean by "efficient", though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const arr = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3];

// use reduce for that.

const result = arr.reduce((result, item) => {
  const count = result[item];
  
  if (count === undefined) {
    result[item] = 1;
  } else {
    result[item] += 1;
  }
  
  return result;
}, {});

// You'll get the result similar to this: {[item]: [count]}

// And then you can transform it into entries array:

const entries = Object.entries(result);

// entries are [[item, count], ...];

// And then sort
 
const sorted = entries.sort((entryA, entryB) => entryA[1] - entryB[1]);

// You'll have ascending sorted array by count.

console.log(sorted);
```

Comment: You need to return 'result' not 'count'

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might do the trick:

```js
const data = ["10", "7", "5", "4", "4", "7", "7", "4", "5", "4"];

const result = data.reduce((r, c) => (r[c] = (r[c] || 0) + 1, r), {});

var keys=Object.keys(result).sort((a,b)=>result[b]-result[a]); // sorted keys

console.log(keys.map(k=>k+':'+result[k])); // output, ordered by keys
```

It is up to you how you want to return the results. `result` contains the count and `keys` the actual values.

Answer (score 0):

> I think the best output would be something like `[{number, frequency}, ...]`

Actually these are not valid JavaScript `objects` inside your output `array`, if you want to show them as pairs you can use an `array` of `arrays` instead of this, the result will be like this:

```
[[number, frequency], ...]
```

In your code you were almost there, but you just need to map the result of your first `reduce` call to get the desired pair:

```js
let values = ["10", "4", "4", "4", "7", "7"];

var map = values.reduce(function(p, c) {
  p[c] = (p[c] || 0) + 1;
  return p;
}, {});

var newTypesArray = Object.keys(map).map(function(k) {
  return [+k, map[k]];
}).sort((a,b) => b[1] - a[1]);

console.log(newTypesArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.entries()` over the object you got from `reduce` now sorting the array of key-value pairs and finally mapping to the array of `{number, frequency}`:

```js
let values = ["10", "4", "4", "4", "7", "7"]


var map = Object.entries(values.reduce(function(p, c) {
                   p[c] = (p[c] || 0) + 1;
                     return p;
                 }, {}))
                .sort((a, b) => a[1] < b[1])
                .map((a) => ({[a[0]]:a[1]}));
console.log(map);
```